# How to create table with datetime in its name using postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, psql

Is there a way to create a table with date time on it's name purely using postgres sql.

Consider the typical create table:

```
CREATE TABLE someNewTable AS SELECT .... FROM someSourceTable WHERE date >= somedate AND date <somedate;
```

What I need is to append the time stamp in a table name. The time stamp is dynamically created. I know this is not a common way but needed for archiving purpose. So is there a way to do this in pure postgres sql?

```
CREATE TABLE someNewTableYYYYMMDDHHMMSS AS SELECT .... FROM someSourceTable WHERE date >= somedate AND date <somedate;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll have to write the SQL statement dynamically through script like a Stored Procedure, or some outside scripting like bash, python, vbscript, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you want to execute a dynamic query:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Then you need something like this:

`execute 'CREATE TABLE someNewTable' ||
    to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS') ||
    ' AS SELECT .... FROM someSourceTable WHERE date >= somedate AND date < somedate;'`

Or if you want to run it in `psql` then you need to use also `DO` operator:

`DO $$
begin
    execute 'CREATE TABLE someNewTable' ||
    to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS') ||
    ' AS SELECT .... FROM someSourceTable WHERE date >= somedate AND date < somedate;'
end
$$ language plpgsql;`

Comment: Also to note, the EXECUTE command is not a standard sql therefore will always need the DO $$ BEGIN .... language plpgsql;